# Understanding SQL Aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I understand the concept of SQL aliases, but in the following doctrine query language example, the alias is at the front of the table names, as well as following behind them. Could someone help explain whats happening in this query? I want to try to get a better understanding of whats happening before i attempt to alter it.

```
public function getByDomain($domain)
  {
    return $this->createQuery('d')->select('d.*, c.*, p.*, cl.*')
            ->innerJoin('d.Table1 c')
            ->innerJoin('c.Table2 p')->innerJoin('c.Table3 cl')
            ->where('d.name=?',$domain)->fetchOne();
  }
```

Comment: I think the part before the "table" name is the database name, not an alias.

Comment: But they all exist in the same db, and the part before the table name doesn't remain constant. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Are you sure they're in the same database? Usually `a.b` means database `a`, table `b` in that context.

Comment: Quite certain @tadman. Is there any other info i could provide that would give you greater context?

Comment: If you're asking for a different database you're going to get one, so if the "part before" isn't consistent you're accessing different databases even if you're not intending to. What does `SHOW DATABASES` say? In this case you're implying that database `d` has one table, database `c` has another. Then you go and create an alias that confuses things since `c` then refers to that table. If they are all in the same database, don't mention the database in your query.

Comment: @tadman This is not something i have written. I'm asking because i have no experience with joining tables. I'm trying to get an understanding of what is going on so that i can manipulate or change it to obtain the desired result. Show Databases lists the only db present in this project.

Comment: Based on the example given here it's highly probable those are databases, but your actual code might be different. Can you watch what queries are generated?

Comment: Do you see those relationships defined in your `schema.yml`?

Comment: I think the author of that code chose aliases that are the same as the database names to make the code confusing.

Comment: I guess this piece of code is coming from a ***Table.class.php, so the "d" alias stands for the current table. So, you're asking doctrine to select all the properties of the current model, and all the entities of the joined tables

Comment: @ilSavo it most certainly is. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are calling `$this->createQuery()` from inside a method that resides in a class that extends Doctrine_Table.  The `createQuery()` method takes one parameter `$alias`, and returns a Doctrine_Query object with the 'from' automatically added in (that is why there is no `->from()` call in the statement).

The full code probably looks like this:

```
class DomainTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function getByDomain($domain)
  {
    return $this->createQuery('d')->select('d.*, c.*, p.*, cl.*')
            ->innerJoin('d.Table1 c')
            ->innerJoin('c.Table2 p')->innerJoin('c.Table3 cl')
            ->where('d.name=?',$domain)->fetchOne();
  }
}
```

In Doctrine, the alias can be used in front of the other model names you want to perform a join on.  Doctrine will automatically determine the foreign keys if you have the proper relations defined in your schema files.

So this code is selecting all columns from Domain, Table1, Table2 and Table3 where the Domain.name column matches $domain, and only returns 1 result (LIMIT 1).